# Windows 10 auto hibernation with the lid closed

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate

I have an Acer Predator G591 with Windows 10 V 1803 Build 17134. Sleep and hibernate functions work just fine when the laptop lid is not closed. It first sleeps and then, after the set time, hibernates.

However, if the lid *is* closed (it's set to sleep if it is) it never goes into hibernation from sleep. I have a Lenovo Yoga 720 as well that works just fine and hibernates as told.

I have searched for several months online and tried everything. It just doesn't do it. I've tried: hibernate on, off, Windows clean install, all the power plan settings... nothing seems to affect it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not set it to hibernate when the lid is closed?

Comment: That is an option, true. However, this is more of a " I hate it when it's not doing what it's supposed to" story. Will sleep better at night knowing it works. :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Search for Power Options and open it
3. Open 'change plan settings' for the plan that is selected
4. Open 'change advanced power settings'
5. Expand the Sleep tab
6. Check 'Hibernate after' settings

I think this will fix your issue

Comment: As mentioned before, when the lid is up, it works. Settings are to hibernate after 2 hours. When lid is closed that option never executes. It stays in  the sleep mode

Comment: Check this out  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power-winpc/windows-10-sleep-turns-into-hibernate-after-a/0dfa78f5-6383-44ec-af96-d161ff4c09d1

Comment: Thread addresses general hibernation work. (disable / enable). I'm passed that stage. I have a more specific problem. I have already done all the windows troubleshooting, plan deletion and settings change.